# how to stretch part of object

Tags: mesh, extrude

How can I stretch a part of an object ?

I selected one side of the area I'm hoping to stretch (just want to add 2/3 cm) but if I press E (extrude) it's going in a weird angle, and don't seems to be the solution anyway.

How should I proceed?

[image: Model in Blender]

Comment: Ok, I found a way to extrude only with Y using the UI submenu, but that's still going inside the object, should I cut the object in two part, extrude, then put it back together?

Comment: When you say stretch do you mean the part that is highlighted should be longer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found something, but surly is not the right way to do it, also having some issue with this method:

1. Select one part of the side
2. SHIFT + D to duplicate
3. Delete the primary part of the side you just duplicate
4. in edit mode select the vertex you want to stretch.
5. press E then right click to cancel.
6. on the submenu add the value you want (4cm in Z in my case)
7. move it back together.

In my case it's not really smooth

[image: Result]

Comment: Don't look smooth on blender, but the STL look smooth in the OS viewer or in a slicer software (3D Printing)

Comment: Why don't you select the half of the model and move it along the Y axis?